# Find the size of 3D objects in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

I apologize if it's been asked before, but it's pretty hard to sort through all the false positives.

I'm looking to measure the size of different 3d objects so I can pass them to binvox, if possible somewhat generalized so I don't have to manually sort by file type. Essentially in code what I can do by opening stuff in 3d builder and looking at the values below.

I'm using .net framwork 4.8 and have tried Aspose.3D but can't figure out how actually measure the entire geometry rather than single nodes.

Since I'm apparently incapable of being clear when I want to: Not trying to figure out size from pictures or something. Looking for existing implementation of essentially going through the coordinates of every node in a wavefront object file, remembering the highest and lowest, then taking the difference for x, y and z.

This is something I'm doing privately, no homework, project or licensing concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in a [minimum bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) such as an AABB.

If that's not enough an oriented bouding box would provide more accurate bounds.

Basically a method `Encapsulate` which encompasses a point and inflates the box accordingly.

Here are two examples you can get inspiration from:

[Unity Bounds](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Geometry/Bounds.cs)

[SharpDX OrientedBoundingBox](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Mathematics/OrientedBoundingBox.cs)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ended up just converting everything to wavefront obj and using a parser for that. I'm certain a bounding box will be the right solution in many cases however.